# How to validate a json array with edittext

Tags: android, arrays, json

Here is my android code, I want to validate the pincode which I fetch from the json, so I have added an `EditText` and `Button`, but I dont know where to implement and how to implement.

As per the following code, I get a bunch of pincode from the json file and it prints on a `ListView`. Now there will be a `EditText` and a `Button`, when I put any pincode which I fetched, it should give me a toast with `true` or `false`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    Button bt;
    EditText et;

    private static String url = "http://52.206.14.188:8080/Configuration";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

         bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.check);
         et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.val);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    JSONArray Source = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    JSONObject config = Source.getJSONObject(6);
                    JSONObject configVal = new JSONObject(config.getString("configurationVal"));
                    JSONArray areas = configVal.getJSONArray("availableAreas");
                    ArrayList<String> pincodes = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < areas.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject area = areas.getJSONObject(i);
                        pincodes.add(area.getString("pincode"));

                        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> contact = new HashMap<>();
                        contact.put("pincode", pincodes);
                        contactList.add(contact);

                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"pincode"}, new int[]{R.id.title});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you wanted to validate your json output pincode with standard pincode or validate with edittext's pincode ?

Comment: so you want to type pincode in the field and show if it can be found in the list or not?

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when u user want do press button 
create this event

```
  YourButtton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if(contactList.contains(YourEditText.getText().toString.trim())) {
        //its yes
    } else {
               //its false});
```

Comment: Where to implement in the code can anyone edit my code please

Comment: @GokulKannan i think u must use in adapter SimpleAdapter 
or use it after setAdatpter inside onPostExecute() if its true tick near my answer :)

Comment: @GokulKannan Man what are u doing he compy my answer and u set tic on this qeustion i say  i think u must use in adapter SimpleAdapter or use it after setAdatpter inside onPostExecute() he just write it xD

Answer (score 1):

When the user presses the button, you need to check whether the input made by user exists in your list or not.

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String input = et.getText();
        if(contactList.contains(input)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Yes",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
        } else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "No",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: edited your code as per your request:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.stetho.server.http.HttpHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import tv.accedo.airtel.wynk.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    Button bt;
    EditText et;

    private static String url = "http://52.206.14.188:8080/Configuration";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.check);
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.val);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ArrayList<String> pincodes = new ArrayList<String>();
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            et.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    JSONArray Source = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    JSONObject config = Source.getJSONObject(6);
                    JSONObject configVal = new JSONObject(config.getString("configurationVal"));
                    JSONArray areas = configVal.getJSONArray("availableAreas");
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < areas.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject area = areas.getJSONObject(i);
                        pincodes.add(area.getString("pincode"));
                         HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> contact = new HashMap<>();
                    contact.put("pincode", pincodes);
                    contactList.add(contact);
                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            et.setEnabled(true);

            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"pincode"}, new int[]{R.id.title});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);


            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String input = et.getText().toString().trim();
                    if(pincodes.contains(input)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Yes",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "No",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should i place this

Comment: after you have the json and contactList ready. you can disable the edittext before that to disallow user input

Comment: As i am beginner i dont know were to implement can you edit the code which i uploaded plz.

Comment: But `contactList` is not simple `Arraylist`, its `ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>`. How `contains` will work?

Comment: You saved me :D

Comment: @Udit this code has a possible bug. you update collection on background thread, and then read from it on the main thread, so you can have race effect; use synchronizedList/synchronizedMap instead or create the collection in onPostExecute (which is executed on the main thread)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to check the validity of a Json, then use this function to validate the json : (import org.json.*;)

```
 public boolean isValidJSON(String test) {
     try {
         new JSONObject(test); // check for json object
     } catch (JSONException ex) {
         // if no json object check for JSONArray
         try {
             new JSONArray(test);
         } catch (JSONException ex1) {
             return false; // no 'json object'/'json Array' found therefor returning false
         }
     }
     return true; }
```